# Iterate thru nested maps in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create Hosted zones and Route53 records in it in AWS.
For that reason I am creating such a variable:

```
variable "hosted_zones_domains" {
  description = "Map of hosted zones to their domains and corresponding IPs"
  type = map(map(string))
  default = {
    "first-example.com" = {
       "beta.first-example.com"  = "192.168.0.1",
       "stage.first-example.com" = "192.168.0.2",
       "prod.first-example.com" = "192.168.0.3"
    },
    "second-example.com" = {
       "beta.second-example.com"  = "192.168.1.1",
       "stage.second-example.com" = "192.168.1.2",
       "prod.second-example.com" = "192.168.1.3"
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to create Hosted zones

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "subdomain_zone" {
  for_each = var.hosted_zones_domains
  name     = each.key
    
  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how to iterate through the inner map to get records names and values and use it in aws_route53_record resource.

Comment: And how were you planning on using the IP addresses related to the record? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this is how I make that to work.

in my root directory I've added locals

```
locals {
  name             = "eks"
  eks_cluster_name = "${local.name}-${var.environment}"
  hosted_zones_domains = {
    "first-example.com" = toset([
      "app1",
      "app2",
      "app3"
    ]),
    "second-example.com" = toset([
      "app1",
      "app2",
      "app3"
    ])
    }
  hosted_zones_domains_list = { for zone, domains in local.hosted_zones_domains : zone => tolist(domains) }
  zone_domain_pairs = flatten([
    for zone, domains in local.hosted_zones_domains_list : [
      for domain in domains : {
        zone   = zone
        domain = domain
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Then passed that to submodule
zone_domain_pairs       = local.zone_domain_pairs

And then in submodule something like that

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "subdomain_zone" {
  for_each = toset([for pair in var.zone_domain_pairs : pair.zone])

  name     = each.key

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "zone_records" {
  for_each = { for pair in var.zone_domain_pairs : "${pair.zone}.${pair.domain}" => pair }

  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.subdomain_zone[each.value.zone].id
  name    = each.value.domain
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [aws_lb.eks_alb.dns_name]
}
```

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The main rule for `for_each` is that you need a map with one element per instance of the resource you want to declare.

In this case, your `for_each` meets that requirement for the *zones* -- each element of the top-level map represents one zone -- but it's not yet suitable for declaring the records themselves. You'll need to derive a new map that has one element per record across all of the zones.

You can derive a suitable flattened map with one element per *recordset* (which Route53 confusingly calls a "record") like this:

```
locals {
  all_records = tomap(merge([
    for zone_name, records in var.hosted_zones_domains : {
      for hostname, ip_addr in records : hostname => {
        zone_name = zone_name
        ip_addr   = ip_addr
      }
    }
  ]...))
}
```

With the default value you showed for the variable, the value of `local.all_records` would be the following:

```
tomap({
  "beta.first-example.com" = {
    zone_name = "first-example.com"
    ip_addr   = "192.168.0.1"
  }
  "stage.first-example.com" = {
    zone_name = "first-example.com"
    ip_addr   = "192.168.0.2"
  }
  "prod.first-example.com" = {
    zone_name = "first-example.com"
    ip_addr   = "192.168.0.3"
  }
  "beta.second-example.com" = {
    zone_name = "second-example.com"
    ip_addr   = "192.168.1.1"
  }
  "stage.second-example.com" = {
    zone_name = "second-example.com"
    ip_addr   = "192.168.1.2"
  }
  "prod.second-example.com" = {
    zone_name = "second-example.com"
    ip_addr   = "192.168.1.3"
  }
})
```

Notice that the zone names are now part of the values of the map, and that the records themselves are toplevel.

Your record names already include the name of the zone they belong to, so the record name alone is a sufficient unique key for tracking each element, which avoids the usual need to concatenate multiple keys together when doing flattening in this way. If you'd like to see an example which *does* need key concatenation (In case you need to solve a similar problem in future where the inner keys are not sufficiently unique, refer to [Flattening nested structures for `for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each) for another example which achieves a similar effect in a different way.)

You can then use `local.all_records` as the `for_each` for your Route53 zone resource:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "example" {
  for_each = local.all_records

  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.subdomain_zone[each.value.zone_name].id
  name    = each.key
  type    = "A"
  records = [each.value.ip_addr]
}
```

Notice that `each.value.zone_name` will always match one of the keys from the original `var.hosted_zones_domains` value, and so will also match one of the instance keys of `aws_route53_zone.subdomain_zone`. Therefore you can use this connection to correlate the records with the zones so that each record ends up attached to the zone it ought to be attached to.

Comment: I am receiving below error which I don't understand to be fair.

Comment: │ Error: creating Route 53 Record: InvalidInput: Invalid request: Expected exactly one of [AliasTarget, all of [TTL, and ResourceRecords], or TrafficPolicyInstanceId], but found none in Change with [Action=CREATE, Name=beta3.mintra.dev.beta.mintra.dev, Type=A, SetIdentifier=null]
│       status code: 400, request id: 04801ac6-e878-444e-861b-da3595e46c92
│ 
│   with module.ALB.aws_route53_record.zone_records["beta3.mintra.dev"],
│   on ../../modules/ALB/main.tf line 217, in resource "aws_route53_record" "zone_records":
│  217: resource "aws_route53_record" "zone_records" {
│ 
╵

Comment: Cool... that sounds like you made enough progress that Terraform Core was able to understand what resource instances you wanted to declare and now you have a separate error coming from the AWS provider. I suggest starting a separate question for that, because I expect it will require AWS expertise to answer, rather than Terraform expertise. Also, it'll be a good opportunity to include your latest configuration in your new question so that it's actually answerable.